# Combine AngularJS, BackboneJS with Component-centric frameworks such as ExtJS, YUI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, extjs

We are looking at refactoring/enhancing our javascript applications at work.

On the one hand we need some top-notch widgets that only some libraries out there can provide, namely: **extjs**, **qooxdoo**.

But on the other hand, there are a number of frameworks out there which provide a nice architectual MV* framework, namely **AngularJS** and **BackboneJS**. (AngularJS has almost become an industry standard).

As I see it there exists this 'frameworks spectrum' and these two framework types sit on either end of that spectrum.

Are they mutually exclusive, or can they complement each other? Each technology seems to be focused on a different area. We would like to have both. Ie. It would be awesome if extjs *(for the widgets!)* and Angular *(for the MVC architecture!)* could work together, but googling has revealed nothing - it seems like they are meant to compete with each other.

Comment: Ext already has MVC and it's being improved in 5.x: http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-viewcontrollers-in-ext-js-5

Comment: so this is kindof what angular and backbone offer?

Comment: Yes, the same pattern.

Comment: With qooxdoo it is also very easy to implement a clean MVC architecture. It is also completely free!

Answer (score 1):

They are not mutually exclusive. Use angular for manipulating and loading views, getting date etc..... Include component framework (or individual components) by writing [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for angular. This is how I'd do it.